# how to assign object in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, iterator

how to assign the object in object and filter the value which pass and fail;

the input is:

```
    [
      {
        name: 'John',
        score: 90,
        time: 'evening'
      },
      {
        name: 'Doni',
        score: 68,
        time: 'morning'
      },
      {
        name: 'Jiu',
        score: 50,
        time: 'evening'
      },
      {
        name: 'Shin',
        score: 92,
        time: 'morning'
      },
    ];
```

and i want the output like this :

```
{
  "evening": {
    "pass": [
      {
        "name": "John",
        "score": 90
      }
    ],
    "fail": [
      {
        "name": "jiu",
        "score": 50
      }
    ]
  },
  "morning": {
    "pass": [
      {
        "name": "Shin",
        "score": 92
      }
    ],
    "fail": [
      {
        "name": "Doni",
        "score": 68
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

do we need to use Object.assign for this ? and how many loop we use for this ?? 
i do love to know how to add another string in the object beside that ouput, 
thanks

Comment: *do we need to use Object.assign for this?* Not necessarily. *and how many loop we use for this?* You do not want to know how many loops you need, let the code handle that for you.

Comment: yepp, do u know how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
const data = [{ name: 'John', score: 90, time: 'evening' }, { name: 'Doni', score: 68, time: 'morning' }, { name: 'Jiu', score: 50, time: 'evening' }, { name: 'Shin', score: 92, time: 'morning' }, ];

const grp = (d, p) => d.reduce((r,c) => (r[c[p]] = [...r[c[p]] || [], c], r), {})
const grpV = (d, rng) => d.reduce((r,{name, score}) => {
  let key = score > rng ? 'pass' : 'fail'
  r[key] = [...r[key] || [], {name, score}]
  return r
}, {})

const r = Object.entries(grp(data, 'time')).map(([k,v]) => ({[k]: grpV(v, 75)}))

console.log(r)
```

The idea is the group 2 times one on the `time` and 2nd on the `score`.

**`grp`**: function to group by a property (in this case 'time') which returns an object with 2 properties: `evening` and `morning` each of which is an array containing the classes.

**`grpV`**: function to group by value (in this case `75`) which returns an object with 2 properties: `pass` and `fail` each of which is an array containing the classes.

On the end once we have those `tools` we are saying ... give me the `entries` of the grouped by `time` object and for each of the groups ... group by score.

Here how something like this could look like if we ware using **`lodash`**:

```js
const data = [{ name: 'John', score: 90, time: 'evening' }, { name: 'Doni', score: 68, time: 'morning' }, { name: 'Jiu', score: 50, time: 'evening' }, { name: 'Shin', score: 92, time: 'morning' }, ];

const partition = (x, p) => _(x)
  .partition(y => y.score > p)
  .map((x,i) => ({ [i==0 ? 'pass': 'fail']: _.omit(x[0], 'time')}))
  .value()

const r = _(data)
  .groupBy('time')
  .mapValues(x => partition(x, 75))
  .value()

console.log(r)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Adding it as an example since it does help with readability of what the ES6 example is doing to some extend.

Comment: hmmm it seems difficult for newbie to understand those syntax

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot of ways to do this. The simplest is probably to make a base object that represent your empty results. Then loop over the students and fill the arrays:

```js
let students = [{name: 'John',score: 90,time: 'evening'},{name: 'Doni',score: 68,time: 'morning'},{name: 'Jiu',score: 50,time: 'evening'},{name: 'Shin',score: 92,time: 'morning'},];

// Empty case
let base =  {
        "evening": {"pass": [], "fail": []},
        "morning": {"pass": [], "fail": []}
}

const PASSING = 70

students.forEach(({name, score, time}) => {
    let key = score >= PASSING ? 'pass' : 'fail'
    base[time][key].push({name, score})
})
console.log(base)
```

This makes is easy to have empty arrays, which is probably what you want if there are no students in a particular category.

EDIT based on comment:

To support arbitrary times, you can just create the times on the object as you find them. `reduce()` is good for this, but you could also use a regular loop. For example with an added `afternoon` time:

```js
let students = [{name: 'Mark',score: 95,time: 'afternoon'}, {name: 'John',score: 90,time: 'evening'},{name: 'Doni',score: 68,time: 'morning'},{name: 'Jiu',score: 50,time: 'evening'},{name: 'Shin',score: 92,time: 'morning'},];

const PASSING = 70

let result = students.reduce((obj, {name, score, time}) => {
    if (!obj[time]) obj[time] = {'pass': [], 'fail': [] }

    let key = score >= PASSING ? 'pass' : 'fail'
    obj[time][key].push({name, score})

    return obj
}, {})


console.log(result)
```

Comment: how about if we other times, midnight, noon? should we create it on base variable? can u use that by function

Comment: @ZrClassic If you are going to have arbitrary time categories, you will be better off building the object as you go. That will be a more general solution, but also more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are more elegant ways to do this. But this one is probably one of the simplest beginner-friendly ways you can go about this.

I loop through the input array, check the existence of the `.time` values as keys on the `output` object and create the `pass` and `fail` keys. Then evaluate the `.score` against the `passingScore` and push the necessary data to it.

Should be pretty easy to understand once you see and try the code below:

```js
const data =   [
      {name: 'John',score: 90, time: 'evening'},
      {name: 'Doni',score: 68, time: 'morning'},
      {name: 'Jiu',score: 50, time: 'evening'},
      {name: 'Shin',score: 92, time: 'morning'},
      {name: 'Fubar',score: 75, time: 'noon'},
    ];
    
    
function formatData(data){
   const passingScore = 75;
   const output = {};

   data.forEach(function(item){
      if(!output[item.time]) output[item.time] = {pass: [], fail: []};

      const stud = { name: item.name, score: item.score };
        
      if(item.score >= passingScore) output[item.time]['pass'].push(stud)
      else output[item.time]['fail'].push(stud)  
   });

   return output;
}

console.log(formatData(data));
```

Comment: this is the perfect one for beginner